# Is it possible to register the different callback function for every response in Serial Port

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I am currently developing a WPF application communication with the embedded board via Serial Port, I have to send more than 2 to 3 commands

1) Connect

2) Send Data

3) Disconnect

Currently, I have used `serialPort.DataReceived` like:

```
serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
```

port_DataReceived callback method:

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Which is getting called for every command (Connect, Send Data, Disconnect).

So is it possible to register different method for each command like?

```
serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceivedForConnect);

serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceivedForSendData);

serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceivedDisconnect);
```

Comment: The `SerialPort` can't distinguish between your Commands because he receives serialized data (bytes?) and doesn' t know what they stand for. Did you define a Communication-Protocoll? If so, you could add a prefix (identifier) or use the existent to identify and relay the data to the according callback.

Comment: Yes protocols are defined n have there different function for these three commands

Comment: Can we register event inside those three methods?

Comment: You can create your own `Event` properties (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/) for these higher-level events but see also reactive extensions for .NET which offers a better pub-sub approach.

Comment: @IanMercer request to post as an answer if you have time

Comment: @LittleBit I am sending the frame of 24 bytes one by one but How would I restrict next frame until the response of first is not received?

Comment: Reserve/Block the `SerialPort` until an answer has been sent or a `Timeout` occured. A `Semaphore`/`Lock` is suitable for this.

Comment: @LittleBit Can you share some reference code?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But there are tons of examples how to use them. Simply pick one and combine it with your write/read `Methods` of the `SerialPort`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is it possible to register different method for each command like?

No, it's not. The `SerialPort` class only raises the `DataReceived` event to indicate that *some* data has been received.

It's then up to you to interpret the data and how to do this depends on the data being read. There is a basic example available on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: I am sending the frame of 24 bytes one by one but How would I restrict next frame until the response of first is not received?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Comment: Have added have a look stackoverflow.com/q/55026042/7124761